How can i clustering a weighted graph by any mean? networkx or other algorithms?
i want to cluster a weighted graph for recommendation, but the graph size is too large for networkx to cluster, about 100k node needed to be cluster, 40k user node and 60k item node. it took too long time to make it happen, give me another method to cluster the weighted graph efficiently?
